# R-square and Intrumental Regression

Tags: regression, econometrics, r-squared, instrumental-variables

Given that a linear regression model has been estimated using instruments can R-square then be interpreted in the usual fashion (as in linear regression without instruments)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

$R^2$ in instrumental variables regression is not useful.

Since one of the explanatory variables $x$ is correlated with the error $\epsilon$ we can't decompose the variance of the outcome $y$ into $\beta^2 Var(x) + Var(\epsilon)$, so the obtained $R^2$ has neither a natural interpretation, nor can it be used for computation of F statistics. Additionally, $R^2$ in instrumental variables regression can be negative so it makes not difference for whether you use
$$R^2 = \frac{MSS}{TSS} \quad \text{or} \quad R^2 = 1- \frac{RSS}{TSS}$$
because when $RSS>TSS$, then we also have that $MSS = TSS - RSS < 0$.

which makes little sense.

Comment: Upvoted for high quality answer.